# Механизм удаления постов в блоге?

Tags: yii2, framework, background

В проекте блог вынесен как отдельный модуль. Если удалять в админ.панели в backend пост, то debage не фиксирует ошибок, приходится закрывать страницу через диспетчер задач, т.к. браузер зависает, и посты удаляются только в базе.

BlogController (D:\sites\site\yii2\vendor\illyas\yii2-blog\controllers)

```html
<?php

namespace illyas\blog\controllers;
        

use Yii;
use common\models\ImageManager;
use medeyacom\blog\models\BlogSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;


/**
 * BlogController implements the CRUD actions for Blog model.
 */
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                    'delete-image' => ['POST'],
                    'sort-image' => ['POST'],

                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Blog models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new BlogSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Blog model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Blog model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new \illyas\blog\models\Blog();
        $model->sort = 50;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Blog model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Blog model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
   

    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }



    public function actionDeleteImage()
    {
        if(($model = ImageManager::findOne(Yii::$app->request->post('key'))) and $model->delete()){
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }

    public function actionSortImage($id)
    {
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            $post = Yii::$app->request->post('sort');
            if($post['oldIndex'] > $post['newIndex']){
                $param = ['and',['>=','sort',$post['newIndex']],['<','sort',$post['oldIndex']]];
                $counter = 1;
            }else{
                $param = ['and',['<=','sort',$post['newIndex']],['>','sort',$post['oldIndex']]];
                $counter = -1;
            }
            ImageManager::updateAllCounters(['sort' => $counter], [
               'and',['class'=>'blog','item_id'=>$id],$param
               ]);
    
            ImageManager::updateAll(['sort' => $post['newIndex']], [
                    'id' => $post['stack'][$post['newIndex']]['key']
                ]);
                return true;
            }
            throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException();
        }

         /**
             * Finds the Blog model based on its primary key value.
             * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
             * @param integer $id
             * @return Blog the loaded model
             * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
             */

    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = \illyas\blog\models\Blog::find()->with('tags')->andWhere(['id'=>$id])->one()) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}

0
Report Icon Report
Reply Icon MultiQuote
Reply Icon Reply
Edit icon Edit
   Go
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте проверку:

```html
if(empty($this->image)){
//выполнится код, если:
//"" (пустая строка)
//0 (целое число)
//0.0 (дробное число)
//"0" (строка)
//NULL
//FALSE
//array() (пустой массив)
//$var; (переменная объявлена, но не имеет значения)
}
```